# Member of Local Administrator group but can't run cmd as admin

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, group-policy

I am part of a domain, my personal user account is not the domain admin. However, I am a member of the local Administrators group. Even so, I can't open CMD as admin! When I try, it asks for the credentials of my user (which is part of the administrators localgroup), and when I enter them correctly, it fails to elevate!

What is really going on here? How can I remove this unintended restriction without having to login to my domain admin account, **and** without doing changes on only my machine?

Comment: The action you describe requires the domain administrator.  Any permissions you have as a local administrator are override by the domain group policy

Comment: Can you run other programs as Administrator, or do they all prompt for elevated credentials?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you make a bit of a conflicting statement.

> How can I remove this unintended restriction without having to login to my domain admin account, and without doing changes on only my machine?

The purpose of a domain account is centralized administration, in other words, network policies supersede local policies.  To run local admin, you need to log into the local machine, not the domain account.

When making changes as admin on the local account, changes would only apply to your machine, hence the whole point of it being local.

Centralized administration of IT infrastructure is designed to stop you from doing what you are trying to do.  If at all possible, I suggest contacting your domain admin.